# Linking failing with Xlinker file not found error

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am trying to compile a Xcode project which was a Xcode 3.2 project with Xcode 4. I am getting the following error.

> ld: file not found: -Xlinker collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Unable to figure out the issue.

And this happens only when I use the Gcc4.2 compiler. When I use LLVM it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ApplicationLinkingIssues you might have framework references to old locations that do not exist anymore. Check the library list in MyProject.xcodeproj / Targets / Build Phases / Link Binary with Libraries, maybe they have to be removed and added again. Do a Product / Clean because XCode often does not realise changes in the build settings.